# Naming functions for the past, present, and future tense?

Tags: api, naming-conventions, naming

I'm trying to come up with some clear and concise names for a Permission class that lets you check if a permission is, was, or will be, allowed/denied.  I'm at a loss for what to call the future tense.

```
class Permission:
  def can_read()
  def could_read()
  def will_read()?
  def will_be_readable()?
```

I'm most partial to `will_read()`, but it sounds funny.  `will_be_readable()` is clear, but its kinda long, and `will_be_read()` sounds misleading.

Comment: What kind of permission system tracks the past, current *and* future availavility of an item?

Comment: Its for auditing changes that happen to the item.  If something adds or removes a permission, it gets marked as such. Then, later, when the object is saved, it logs those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, English really has a problem here, with no future tense of "can"! What about switching to (say) `readable_now`, `readable_past`, `readable_future`? If past and future have specific meanings in your case better naming could be worked out here, I'm sure.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are looking for a permission class, the code will be formulated as a question:

```
if (the_user.can_read()) ...
if (the_user.can_read_past()) ...
if (the_user.can_read_future()) ...
```

Apart from that I would try to maintain equal prefixes for the semantically equal function, and I would leave off the suffix for the default/most likely case. I have no real problem sacrificing grammatical correctness for a logical naming structure, even though I like to gear  code towards natural language. So something like that is what I would be going for.

The `will_read()` sounds more like an event that is triggered before the action.

EDIT: I am aware that "`can_read_past`" may be percieved as "can read old stuff". Maybe Scott Evernden's suggestion is better?

Comment: fwiw: .can_read_past() implies that the user can currently read, but only past events.  Perhaps: the_user.had_read() or something along those lines.

Comment: To the unaided eye, yes. I know it's not ideal. I tried to remain consistent assuming that can_read() is the default, expected case, and the other two are variations  of it. I thought of it as "can_read()" with a "past" modifier, not as "can read old stuff". But then again, I'm not a native speaker, so I can't really say how strong the instinctive preference for the latter would be.

Answer (score 2):

was, is, and will_be is clearest to me..
 or maybe readable_before, readable_now, readable_later

Answer (score 0):

Since it is related to if a permission is allowed/denied, maybe there is a more descriptive word than read?


 can_authorize 

 authorized

 scheduled_to_authorize